# What happens to questions closed as blatantly off-topic?

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons, off-topic

The following close reason appears on every single Stack Exchange site when you're voting/flagging to close a question as off-topic:

> **Blatantly off-topic** (this question has nothing to do with [INSERT SCOPE HERE])

Questions that fit to this reason seem to disappear right after the closure. Do they get automatically deleted, or is there something else going on?

Comment: Yes, they are usually deleted by moderators or high rep users.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, *blatantly off-topic* is only available when flagging to close but not when voting to close¹. As users with the [close privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) get shown the close-vote dialogue when trying to flag to close, this means that this option is not available to them at all¹. Once you have the close privilege, you have to use another close reason or a custom close reason instead (which you can then word identically)¹.

The close reason shown below a question is that chosen by the majority of the close voters. As they cannot choose *blatantly off-topic,* **you will never find a question closed with that reason.** If the majority of close voters opt for a custom close reason, you get:

> This question does not appear to be about [scope] within the scope defined in the help center.

but without *blatantly off-topic*.

Once closed, users with the [trusted user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privilege can vote to delete them; two days later, users with the [moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege can do so as well. Moreover, after a week, automatic deletion mechanisms apply.

At any time (before or after closure), diamond moderators can instantly delete the question, which is particularly likely for blatantly off-topic questions.

There is no mechanism, however, that instantly deletes such questions after closure.

---

<sup>¹ except on those sites which have a similar site-specific close reason, e.g., Meta SE (this very site)</sup>

Answer (score 10):

They'll either get deleted by three users who have enough reputation to vote to delete which is at [10k](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) for questions older than three days or at [20k](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) for immediate delete votes.

If they are egregiously off topic then a moderator might well delete immediately too.

If this doesn't happen then there's an [automatic process that deletes closed negatively scoring questions after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/59303).

The other thing that might well be happening is that, as the post is more than likely got a negative score, it is not being shown on the home page, as questions with [a score of -4 or less aren't shown on the home page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62769/59303).