# Does editing a question move it to the front page?

Tags: support, edits

Say, I ask a question. I add details a few days later. Will my question remain in the bottom pile of the feed or be brought to the top of the search list?
Do people use this as a method to bump their answers when it receives very less attention? How are such activities caught? Does the community manually have to check or are software systems set in place to prevent such malpractices?

Comment: Have you considered not asking the question until you have all the details ready?

Comment: But what if the OP provides some details which may aid in providing a solution to the problem as told by Journeyman Geek.

Comment: Adding detail is great. But this question to me sounds like: "I ask a question I know isn't good but I plan on adding detail later"... to which my first thought is: "why not ask the question later when you feel like putting the detail in at the same time?"

Comment: You're right. I edited the question.

Comment: And it is this kind of explosive downvoting that makes me apprehensive of asking questions as a newcomer. And I'm sure that even this comment will be downvoted.

Comment: To answer your new questions: Yes, this is a valid way to get attention for questions without much attention, provided you aren't abusing this (i.e. you are only bumping to provide info related to your attempts to answer the question yourself). Frivolous bumping will cause an automatic moderator flag to be raised, and moderators can take action up to suspending the user or locking the post to prevent edits.

Comment: Comments can't be downvoted, only upvoted.

Comment: Or else I would've been abused in the comment section also

Comment: People here downvote for the same reasons as they do on main Q&A sites: they think you did not do enough research by searching here before asking your question. To be frank, your new questions you edited here are already covered in other questions, but I won't downvote your post, because I'm nice. For some tips for later, see [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: Also, even if this weren't a dupe, this would be too broad, since we generally only allow one specific question per post.

Comment: My main question was highlighted around the malpractice. My bad, I didn't phrase it correctly and specifically point out. Anyway, thanks for the "survival" post. I'll be sure to post as minimally as possible on this site.

Comment: Asking this question in a way, made me learn a lot on how to use this site especially meta.

Comment: And another user has modified the duplicate links so that all the different questions this question covers are linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing a question would likely bump it up the *active* questions list. That said, this *shouldn't* be use simply as a way to bump up a question over time. Edits should improve your question *substantially*  so no single charecter fixes, but if you're adding more relevant details, or simply showing your own work/attempts as part of helping others help you find a solution, its fine.

Comment: What if a user just changes a letter or two to increase the rank of his question? Is there any means of identifying this?

Comment: People will notice (Its shown as modified, and under review history( - and they will be unhappy. And there might be downvotes. So... please no. There's a good reason I added in a bunch of stuff after "Yes, it'll work"

Comment: I asked if they have systems in place which can detect such a practice and reject the edit without the public actually noticing it.

Comment: I don't remember! But don't do it anyway.

Comment: Questions that are [sufficiently downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62769/323179) will be hidden from the front page, but they will still be bumped on the other active list.

Comment: I mainly asked about questions which didn't get attention, not the ones which were downvoted.