# What is the threshold for hiding questions on the main page of main sites, local metas, and MSE?

Tags: support, questions, down-votes, homepage

I've looked around at various questions, but I haven't found a clear place where this is documented.

When posts reach a certain (low) score, a post will stop showing up on the main page of whatever site you are looking at (though you can still see it by going to "Questions" which shows all of them).

What is the threshold for doing this?

And if it is different, what are the thresholds on the main page of main sites, local metas, and MSE specifically?

Comment: That is correct @AnneDauntedGoFundMonica https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62769/161198